# Which is faster for comparing case class object in scala : a) equals(==) method or b) equating hash values

Tags: scala, hash, equals, case-class

Which is faster for comparing object in scala :

a) comparing two case class objects using the equals(==) method or

b) creating hash out of the member variables of object and then comparing that hash.

I think equals method should be faster but my friend argues if we create a string of member variables values and generate its hash and compare it it will be faster as it will do one comparison instead of n comparison which it does in equal method. n being the number of variables.

Comment: `==` compares references, yes? Isn't that equivalent enough to hashes? Generating a string of N variables, then computing its hash could be argued to be more computationally complex than N boolean comparisons

Comment: @cricket_007 in Scala, == is used for checking value equality, not reference equality.

Comment: @JFo Just for case classes, though, right?

Comment: @Vaibhavrtk Comparing hashes does not do the same thing as comparing objects based on their values. You don't have a guarantee that 2 objects with the same hashes are really equal in terms of their values. Are you aware about that?

Comment: @cricket_007 no, for everything. If you want to check reference equality, then you need to use `eq` or `ne` which is defined on `AnyRef`. Of course `==` is just a method and you could override it with whatever you want it to do, but you only should use it to compare objects based on their values.

Comment: Right, right. And hash collisions are possible, so equals is the way to go regardless of performance

Comment: Equal objects should yield the same hash code, but not vise versa. If you're going to rely on hashes for equality, you're going to have a bad time. See the [Pigeon Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Comment: Thanks guys, I will go ahead with equals instead of hash-code then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two strings have the same hashcode:

```
"G9tX"
"FZ79"
hashcode: 2173622
```

So you have to use `equals` to compare to object. In case of the string, if `hashcode` is cashed, you can first compare them. In this case, if hashcodes are not equal, you can be 100% sure the string are not equal to.